# SQL Exception: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed. Why is that?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, resultset, sqlexception

I try to get one piece of data from the database, and suddenly it gives the error: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed. on the line which is

```
while(rs3.next()) {
```

Why is that happening? The code seems to be alright and everything. Here is my code:

```
public DatabaseConnectionClass() {

    idfield = new JTextField("");
    submit = new JButton("go");
    settings = new JButton("settings");
    auto = new JButton("auto");
    add(idfield);
    add(submit);
    add(settings);
    add(auto);
    setLayout(new GridLayout());

    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database1?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "");
        st = con.createStatement();
        con2 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/values?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "");
        st2 = con2.createStatement();


    } catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);



    }
    }
```

And here is the faulty method which activates on pressing on one of the buttons (called auto):

```
 public void getAuto() throws Exception {

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

            String q1 = "SELECT * FROM payments LIMIT 1";
            try {
                rs3=st.executeQuery(q1);
                while(rs3.next()) {
                String ppmail = rs3.getString("mail");
                getData(ppmail);
                rs3.close();

                }} catch (SQLException e) {

                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(e);
                auto.setText("End of records");
            }


            }


}
```

Comment: You are closing the resultset in the loop where you iterate over it . Consider closing it _after_ the loop .

Comment: it still gives me one

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `ResultSet` after you [close](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#close()) it, move `rs3.close();` to `finally` block

```
            }} catch (SQLException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e);
            auto.setText("End of records");
        } finally { 
             if (s3 != null){
                 s3.close();
             }
        }
```

> Releases this ResultSet object's database and JDBC resources immediately

Comment: Converting it into try-with-resources would be a better option most likely.

Comment: @NiceGuy "It still gives me an error" isn't useful information. *What* error does it give you?

Comment: @Amongalen `rs3` isn't a local variable in method

Comment: @user7294900 that's true but that makes things even worse. I can't think of any reason to keep ResultSet global.

Comment: @JonK the same error: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

Comment: @NiceGuy your code is incomplete, basically open and close Connection,PreparedStatement and ResultSet every SQL executed, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html